# QML TreeView change delegate on edit

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qtquick2, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to use QML TreeView in order to replace the ordinary `QTreeView`. Now, I wanted to achieve a similar behavior to `QTreeView`, so that on each double click on an item, the `Text` element should be replaced by an `TextField`  with allows editing of the values.

Now, this is what I got so far in my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    TreeView {
        id: treeView
        anchors.fill: parent

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Value"
            role: "display"
            width: 100
            delegate: Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    id: textDisplay
                    visible: true
                    text: model.display
                }

                TextInput {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    id: textEdit
                    text: model.edit;
                    visible: false

                    onAccepted: {
                        model.edit=textEdit.text
                        textEdit.visible=false
                        textDisplay.visible=true
                    }
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onDoubleClicked: {
                        textDisplay.visible=false;
                        textEdit.visible=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        model: itemModel
    }
}
```

After double click on an value in the `QTreeView` the textEdit shows and the text is hidden, but there is neither a focus in textEdit allowing to change the value nor can I commit the edited value with enter. In case, that I'm loosing focus the value should be also accepted.

My model `itemModel` is basically a `QStandardItemModel` and all items should be editable:

```
Qt::ItemFlags MyModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags=QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
    flags|=Qt::ItemFlag::ItemIsEditable;
    return flags;
}
```

What do I have to do in order to allow for editing of the values?

Comment: You are only setting the TextInput visible, you need to set focus to the element with forceActiveFocus()

Comment: @onion: Many thanks for this simple solution. Now it works.